# Contacts can't be indexed by Launcbar: MacOS Error -67050

Tags: contacts, indexing, launchbar

on macos Sierra 10.12.4 and latest version of LaunchBar I have a problem with indexing Contacts items and now I am sure it is not LaucnBar's fault because I ran it in debug mode and found this in Console:

- UNIX error exception: 17
- MacOS Error -67050

There are bunch of other warnings (as always) which I believe are not relevant like:

> warning: dynamic accessors failed to find @property implementation for
>   'uniqueId' for entity ABCDAddressBookSource while resolving selector
>   'uniqueId' on class 'ABCDAddressBookSource'.  Did you remember to
>   declare it @dynamic or @synthesized in the @implementation ?

Is there anybody else who had this problem with Contacts?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you running the most recent version of LaunchBar (compatible with Sierra)?  Have you contacted the developer of LaunchBar to verify it's not a bug in their application?

Comment: All basic checks have been done before posting here. I even dig in logs and sampled processes in Activity Monitor with no clue.

Comment: Were you able to ask the LaunchBar developer?  From my searching, the console errors you posted are either normal for Sierra or indicative of a [security access error](https://www.osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=-67050).  They might not have anything to do with your problem.

Comment: I get tons of these errors also, but I don’t have LaunchBar. -67050 comes from having a kext that is not properly code-signed. See: https://www.tonymacx86.com/threads/gatebreak-signed-kexts-for-everyone.112306/

Comment: Note: if you have that error, backup your Mac, then run EtreCheck and try to figure out which kext is causing this.